# how do i convert a timespan to a string in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, datetime

It gives an error,

**Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'String' is not valid.**

```
Time.Text = datareader1.GetValue(3)
```

I'm trying to display the data from the `database(MS ACCESS)`, the data display is a `time` type.

Comment: In my answer, I've assumed this is VB. Please could you confirm, and edit your question tags appropriately? (Having tags *just* about Visual Studio isn't terribly useful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `ToString()`:

```
Time.Text = datareader1.GetValue(3).ToString()
```

The fact that you're currently seeing this *at execution time* suggests that you've got `Option Strict` set *off*. (I'm assuming this is VB.) I would suggest having `Option Strict` *on* unless you really, really need it off for deliberate late-binding reasons.